# nginx reverse proxy add request cookie

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have to use reverse proxy for a project. I need to add request cookie in nginx.

The case like:

request comes with header. other servis want to this variable in cookie. I tried many way for resolve this problem. I did not manage to.

Anyone can help me ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want to move parameter from header to cookie? Try something like this:

```
location / {
...
proxy_set_header Cookie "MY_COOKIE_PARAM=${http_my_header_param}; ${http_cookie}";
...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have small question too. I also move variable response cookie to response header. How can i handle it ? 
@CheshirskyCode

Comment: I know two ways for handling this. First. You might use Nginx variable [$upstream_cookie_name](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#var_upstream_cookie_) and instruction add_header. In this case, you should know all cookies which you want to move to. Second. You may use [lua-nginx-module](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module). For example, [set-by-lua](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#set_by_lua_block) and then add_header. Lua-nginx-module is fast and production-ready, but you should write additional logic in lua